# Wordpress/ACF - Get Post Values to Repeater with Select Post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have got 2 custom post type like as products and sells.

Products post type have ACF;

- Title ( pro_title )
- Product Explanation ( pro_exp )
- Product Price ( pro_prc )
- Product Bonus ( pro_bonus )

Sells post type have ACF;

In Repeater:

- Product ( Select Post Object )
- Product Explanation ( sell_pro_exp )
- Product Price ( sell_pro_prc )
- Product Bonus ( sell_pro_bonus )

My question is when I select the product, I want the other information of the product to be printed in the relevant fields in the admin panel.

I do this with Javascript and PHP Function. As you can see in the example below, I can take the product price and print it in the relevant box.

Javascript Code :

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var valueCheck;
    $('#acf-field_5e7c9a8b2e9ca-row-0-field_5e7c9ad82e9cc').on( 'change', function () {
         valueSelect = $(this).val();
         if ( parseInt ( valueSelect ) > 0 ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                action: 'proprice',
                value: valueSelect
            }, 
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            success: function (data) {

               console.log(data);
               if ( data == '') {
                  $('#acf-field_5e7c9a8b2e9ca-row-0-field_5e7c9ad82e9cd-field_5e7c9ad82e9d0').val( '<span>Bu #id: ' +  valueSelect + ' ye ait bir içerik bulunamadı.</span>' );
               }
               else {
                  $('#acf-field_5e7c9a8b2e9ca-row-0-field_5e7c9ad82e9cd-field_5e7c9ad82e9d0').val( data );
               }

            }
    });
         }
    });
});
```

PHP Function Code :

```html
function pricepointer(){
$id = $_POST['value'];
$sonucum =  the_field('pro_prc', $id);
echo $sonucum;
die();
}
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_proprice', 'pricepointer' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_proprice', 'pricepointer' );
```

But i have got a problem. When i add a new product to sells with repeater, selector id and input id change. ( like as : #acf-field_5e7c9a8b2e9ca-**61cb0abc7e269**-field_5e7c9ad82e9cc )

I try adding class to repeater and doing it with :nth-child selector but doesn't work. How can I do this, or is there another way to do this? How can i get all data values into sells with select post in repeater?

Comment: On the page load, I guess you wish to add some of your value am I correct. You are just trying to auto-fill some fields. Please confirm on the same.

Comment: When I select the product on the Sell page, I want the product values to appear in the relevant boxes on this page.